# Option inheritance: setting new defaults and private context

Tags: options, optional-arguments

I'm having issues with inherited options for functions I defined in a package file. Setting new default options doesn't quite work as I expect. Also, a function which I'd like to stay private to the package somehow leaks into the public context…

Consider the package file `OptionInheritanceTest.m`:

```
BeginPackage["OptionInheritanceTest`"]

f2::usage = ""
f3::usage = ""

(* Default options *)
Options[f1] = {Flag1 -> True};
Options[f2] = Join[Options[f1],
                   {Flag2 -> True}];
Options[f3] = Join[{Method -> "A"},
                   Options[f2]];

Begin["`Private`"]

f1[expr_,
   opts:OptionsPattern[]] := {expr,
                              OptionValue[Flag1]};
f2[expr_,
   opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Append[f1[expr,
                                       FilterRules[{opts},
                                                   Options[f1]]],
                                    OptionValue[Flag2]];
f3[expr_,
   opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Append[f2[expr,
                                       FilterRules[{opts},
                                                   Options[f2]]],
                                    OptionValue[Method]];

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

After loading this package in a notebook the commands

```
Options[f1]
f1[x]
Options[f2]
f2[x]
Options[f3]
f3[x]
```

return exactly the desired output. Let's try to set new default options for f3:

```
SetOptions[f3, Flag1 -> False, Flag2 -> False, Method -> "C"];
```

While `Options[f3]` perfectly reflects the new option values the command

```
f3[x]
```

yields

```
{x, True, True, "C"}
```

So the new f3 defaults are not handed down to f1 and f2 when they're called by f3. How can I achieve that?

Also, I would like f1 to remain in the private context, but `Options[f1] = …` seems to export it to the public context. Simply declaring this option in the private block wrecks the option inheritance unfortunately. What is the way to go forward?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A symbol's context is determined by the `Context[]` where it first appears. So, the `::usage` statements for `f1` and `f2` are sufficient to put them into the `` OptionInheritanceTest` `` context. This means you can move the `Options` declarations into `` `Private` `` without bringing `f2` and `f3` into that context. This creates a problem, as the first appearance of `Flag1` and `Flag2` is now in `` OptionInheritanceTest`Private` ``.  There are two solutions to this: either declare them alongside `f2` and `f3` (a `::usage` statement is a good idea), or use string options, e.g. `"Flag1" -> True`, etc.  The second has the advantage that you are not introducing new symbols, but the first allows you to add usage messages which is very helpful to a user.

Additionally, your method for passing options to `f1` and `f2` from higher in the chain is insufficient. The pattern `opts:OptionsPattern[]` only captures what is passed into the function, so you need to pass the entire list of options, e.g. use

```
FilterRules[{opts, Options[f2]}, Options[f1]]
```

instead of just

```
FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f1]]
```

Comment: Since `FilterRules` automatically flattens, `FilterRules[{opts, Options[f2]}, Options[f1]]` is marginally simpler.

Comment: @jkuczm good point, updated my answer.

Comment: "advantage that you are not introducing new symbols" - I don't think "advantage" is always the appropriate word here, but I have expressed my discontent for string options many times before. (I mean, go with it if you think it's best for you; I'm just offering a dissenting opinion.)

Comment: @J.M. both have their good points and bad points. A bad point for symbols is a reduction in the available symbols. Despite that, I prefer symbol options, too, as they show up in the code assist. But, string options are a _way_ of bypassing the need of declaring them in the right context, whether that is sufficient to warrant their use depends on the user.

Comment: Option passing now seems to work. Is it correct to assume that `opts` takes precedence over `Options[f2]`, i.e. options which are explicitly supplied to the function `f2` override any defaults stored in `Options[f2]`?

Comment: I think I prefer the symbol option solution. Where would I attach the `::usage` statement? Is it simply `Flag1::usage`?

Comment: @groovybaby yes, `opts` will override that set via `SetOptions` because they are first in the list. And, yes, `Flag1::usage` is what you use, just like you do for `f2` and `f3`.

Answer (score 5):

Since *Mathematica* version 10 there's `FilterOptions` function from `` GeneralUtilities` `` context, that can be useful here. Using it you don't have to explicitly pass filtering pattern e.g. `Options[f1]` when defining `f2`, it will be automatically inferred from context:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

ClearAll[f1, f2, Flag1, Flag2]
Options[f1] = {Flag1 -> True};
Options[f2] = Join[Options[f1], {Flag2 -> True}];
f1[expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := {expr, OptionValue[Flag1]}
f2[expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Append[
        f1[expr, FilterOptions[opts, Sequence @@ Options[f2]]],
        OptionValue[Flag2]
    ]
```

Now `f2` works as expected:

```
SetOptions[f2, Flag1 -> False, Flag2 -> False];
f1[x]
(* {x, True} *)
f2[x]
(* {x, False, False} *)
f2[x, Flag1 -> True]
(* {x, True, False} *)
f2[x, Flag2 -> True]
(* {x, False, True} *)
f2[x, Flag1 -> True, Flag2 -> True]
(* {x, True, True} *)
```

You can also define your own delegating function that will automatically read default options from given symbols and automatically filter them for function in which it's used:

```
ClearAll[delegateOptions]

delegateOptions::usage = "\
delegateOptions[spec1, spec2, ...] \
returns a sequence of options, extracted from given speci, filtered \
for head surrounding delegateOptions expression. \
Option specification speci can be explicit opt -> val rule or delayed rule, \
a symbol from which default options will be extracted, \
or a list of valid option specifications.";

delegateOptions /: head_[args1___, delegateOptions[opts___], args2___] :=
    head[
        args1,
        Sequence @@ FilterRules[
            Replace[Flatten[{opts}], sym_Symbol :> Options[sym], {1}], 
            Options[head]
        ],
        args2
    ]
```

Now definition of `f2` is slightly simpler instead of `FilterOptions[opts, Sequence @@ Options[f2]]]` you can use `delegateOptions[opts, f2]`:

```
ClearAll[f2]
Options[f2] = Join[Options[f1], {Flag2 -> True}];
f2[expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Append[f1[expr, delegateOptions[opts, f2]], OptionValue[Flag2]];
```

`f2` works the same:

```
SetOptions[f2, Flag1 -> False, Flag2 -> False];
f1[x]
(* {x, True} *)
f2[x]
(* {x, False, False} *)
f2[x, Flag1 -> True]
(* {x, True, False} *)
f2[x, Flag2 -> True]
(* {x, False, True} *)
f2[x, Flag1 -> True, Flag2 -> True]
(* {x, True, True} *)
```

Comment: `FilterOptions[]` is actually [pretty old](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v3/AddOns/Util_FilterOptions-.html) (in fact, even older than that link; it was in the first edition of Maeder's book).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, I didn't know that, I first saw it as part of ``GeneralUtilities` ``.